# Batch Open URLs

Tags: excel, vba, url, web-scraping, automation

I have a worksheet wherein it contains a list of websites in column J, starting in row 3. I would like to have a macro wherein it would batch open all the websites in different tabs on the same browser window.
I have the existing code below.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie          As Object
    Dim c           As Range

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For Each c In Sheets("Common").Range("J3:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Navigate c.Value, CLng(2048)
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

It works for the most part. But somehow it would open tabs on the browser window to which there are no values on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the name of the sheet in front because your are implicitly working off activesheet which is bug prone. E.g.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

From debugging it seems you are finding the wrong end row with xlUp so use xlDown (given you know there are no empty cells between urls)

```
Sheets("Common").Range("J3:J" & Sheets("Common").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row)
```

If you want to use chrome consider [installing selenium basic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181377/6241235). Ensure latest ChromeDriver.exe is in the selenium folder and VBE>Tools>References>Selenium Type Library reference added.

Comment: Is there another way without using selenium?

Comment: Which depending how good your command line is you could write a bat file with urls and simply execute a loop over that via shell in VBA

Comment: Thanks for directing me over to that link. Looks very informative. But I dont think I want to use it though since it would require me to rework the code again since I'm dealing with a list of URLs in a column.

Comment: You can use same idea but concatenate urls from sheet into the shell command

Comment: Its not working, but its ok. I can settle with Internet Explorer.